# Is Factory reset can fix my problem?

Tags: google-play-store, lucky-patcher

I installed lucky patcher and and there's an option there says Install Modded Playstore
then I try what is that then after a while it prompts an error it says not enough space in \system and when I go back in menu I noticed that Play store has gone now Im asking is factory reset can help me in getting back of that play store?
Device:Cloudpad 700

Comment: Reflash your ROM.

Answer (score 3):

A factory restore will likely not help fix your problem, as the error is within the `/system` folder, and *a factory reset only wipes `/data`*.

In Lucky Patcher, you should have an option to revert non-integrated patches of an app from **Lucky Patcher > [App] > Open menu of patches > Remove ODEX with changes**.

If that doesn't work:
You are going to have to manually reinstall the Play Store, which can be found [here](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/google-play-store-5-2-13-apk/).

Comment: It always went into an error it says: not enough space within the System Partition to move the application. Please free up space in /system then try again

Comment: When you try to remove the ODEX with changes?

Comment: yes I already try that

Comment: Have you tried installing the Play Store .apk?